# OneSignal notification custom sound not working

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

I increased notifications in my app through the OneSignal plugin, I would like to customize the sound of the notification, I followed the documentation, but it did not work.

Here's the code i am using:

```
    var notification = new OneSignal.Notification({
    contents: {
        ar: req.body.title,
        en: req.body.titleEn,
    },
    include_player_ids: req.body.includePlayersIds,
    data: req.body.data,
    send_after: req.body.sendAfter,
    delayed_option: "timezone",
    android_sound: "sahwah",
    ios_sound: "sahwah.wav"
});
```

I already put the sound file called sahwah under this path: /platforms/android/res/raw/

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons why a sound may not play in your case:

- The sound file may be too long
- Make sure that the sound file is getting built into your APK by extracting it and making sure it is located in res/raw/.

If shrinking resources is enabled, you can protect sound files from being removed by creating keep.xml in res/raw/ with the following code:

`<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:keep="@raw/sound_file"/>`

Answer (score 1):

I am also faced this issue.
finally i put the sound file android/app/src/main/res/raw/sound_file.mp3
this is working for me.